# How to Add a Countdown Timer on my user page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please Help! I have a user page setup and properly linked to my database. What i want to do is to add a countdown timer of 3 hours for users who have not activated their account. I want that timer to be unique to individual users which will start counting once they register their account and when they login the countdown will be displayed on the page. Please, can anyone help me with a simple code to implement this? Thanks a lot.

PS: I am a dummy in code writing, so I use Dreamweaver to help me with code generation.

Here's my page code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/TurboFund.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "Received1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE users SET AcceptedFrom1=%s WHERE UserID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Received2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['UserIDHiddenField1'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_TurboFund, $TurboFund);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $TurboFund) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "dashboardactivated.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "Received1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE users SET AcceptedFrom1=%s WHERE UserID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Purge'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['UserIDHiddenField2'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_TurboFund, $TurboFund);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $TurboFund) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "dashboardactivated.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

$colname_User = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_User = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_TurboFund, $TurboFund);
$query_User = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_User, "text"));
$User = mysql_query($query_User, $TurboFund) or die(mysql_error());
$row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($User);
$totalRows_User = mysql_num_rows($User);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.3.0.60745 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.responsive.css" media="all">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script.responsive.js"></script>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keywords">


<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { color: #232324; background: ;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-1 {  border-collapse: separate;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-2 { border-style:Solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#7C7C7E; color: #CBCBCD; background: #08BFBC; padding: 0px;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-3 { border-style:Solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#444446; padding: 0px;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-4 { border-bottom-style:Solid;border-left-style:Solid;border-bottom-width:2px;border-left-width:2px;border-bottom-color:#B4B4B6;border-left-color:#B4B4B6; color: #565658; background: #ECECEA;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-5 { border-top-style:Solid;border-right-style:Solid;border-bottom-style:Solid;border-top-width:2px;border-right-width:2px;border-bottom-width:2px;border-top-color:#B4B4B6;border-right-color:#B4B4B6;border-bottom-color:#B4B4B6; color: #565658; background: #ECECEA;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-6 { color: #777779; background: ;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-7 { margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-8 { border-style:Groove;border-top-width:1px;border-right-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-left-width:1px;border-top-color:#B4B4B6;border-right-color:#B4B4B6;border-bottom-color:#B4B4B6;border-left-color:#B4B4B6;  border-collapse: separate;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-9 { border-style:Solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#7C7C7E; color: #FFFFFF; background: #08BFBC; padding: 0px;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-10 { border-style:Groove;border-width:2px;border-color:#444446; color: #777779; background: ; padding: 0px;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-11 { border-right-style:Solid;border-bottom-style:Solid;border-left-style:Solid;border-right-width:2px;border-bottom-width:2px;border-left-width:2px;border-right-color:#B4B4B6;border-bottom-color:#B4B4B6;border-left-color:#B4B4B6; color: #565658; background: #E5E5E6;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-12 { border-style:Solid;border-width:2px;border-color:#7C7C7E; color: #FFFFFF; background: #08BFBC;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-13 { border-style:Solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#444446; color: #777779; background: ;  }
.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-14 { border-right-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-left-style:solid;border-right-width:2px;border-bottom-width:2px;border-left-width:2px;border-right-color:#B4B4B6;border-bottom-color:#B4B4B6;border-left-color:#B4B4B6; color: #565658; background: #E5E5E6;  }
.ie7 .art-post .art-layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .art-post .art-layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
<header class="art-header">

    <div class="art-shapes">
        <div class="art-object1332516260"></div>
<div class="art-object7306249"></div>
<div class="art-object1873331263"></div>

            </div>

<h1 class="art-headline">
    <a href="/">Let's Build your financial life together</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan">Leadership is influence.</h2>





<nav class="art-nav">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="home.php" class="">Home</a></li><li><a href="log-in.php" class="">Log In</a></li><li><a href="sign-up.php" class="">Sign Up</a></li><li><a href="services.php" class="">Services</a></li><li><a href="how-it-works.php" class="">How It Works</a></li><li><a href="contact-us.php" class="">Contact Us</a></li></ul> 
    </nav>


</header>
<div class="art-sheet clearfix">
            <div class="art-layout-wrapper">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content"><article class="art-post art-article">


                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <p><br></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(66, 66, 67); font-size: 22px; font-family: Georgia;"><span style="color: rgb(106, 106, 108);">Welcome!,</span></span> <?php echo $row_User['Username']; ?>.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout layout-item-1">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-2" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 16px;">Dashboard</span></p>
    </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-3" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center; padding-left: 80px;"><span style="color: rgb(66, 66, 67); font-size: 16px;">Account Information &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(66, 66, 67); font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;<a href="" class="art-button">Log Out</a>&nbsp;</span><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img width="283" height="283" alt="" class="art-lightbox" src="images/generic_avatar_300-2.gif" style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; "></p>
    </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-5" style="width: 50%" >
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;">Name:</span> <?php echo $row_User['Fname']; ?></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;"><br></span></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;">Email:</span> <?php echo $row_User['Email']; ?></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;"><br></span></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;">Phone Number:</span> <?php echo $row_User['PhoneNumber']; ?></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;"><br></span></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 14px;">Bank Account Details:</span> <?php echo $row_User['BankAccDetails']; ?></p>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(5, 111, 143); font-size: 18px;"><br></span></p><p>&nbsp;<a href="" class="art-button">Edit Account Info</a>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-6" style="width: 100%" >
        <p><br></p><p><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout-wrapper layout-item-7">
<div class="art-content-layout layout-item-8">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-9" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center;">Donation</span><br></p>
    </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-10" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span style="color: #75D43A;">ACCOUNT HAS BEEN CONFIRMED</span></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-11" style="width: 100%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><br></p><p style="text-align: left;"></p><p style="padding-left: 20px;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">PACKAGE:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $row_User['Donation']; ?>: <?php echo $row_User['StatusDonation']; ?></p>
        <p></p><p style="text-align: center;"><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-6" style="width: 100%" >
        <p><span style="color: rgb(48, 48, 49);"><br></span></p><p><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-12" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Earnings</span><br></p>
    </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-13" style="width: 50%" >
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #25D402;">ACCOUNT IS ACTIVE</span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-14" style="width: 100%" >
        <p style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: center;"><br></p><p style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left;"></p><ul>
          <li><span style="font-size: 14px;">Receive Donation From:</span> <?php echo $row_User['ReceiveFrom']; ?>: <?php echo $row_User['AcceptedFrom1']; ?></li>
        </ul>
        <form action="" method="post" name="Status1" id="Status1" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
          <input name="Confirm" type="checkbox" id="Confirm" value="Confirmed" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
          <label for="Confirm"></label>
          <input name="UpdateButton" type="submit" class="art-button" id="UpdateButton" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Confirm"/>
          <input name="Purge" type="checkbox" id="Purge" value="You Will Be Rematched Soon!" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
             <label for="Purge"></label>
             <input name="UpdateButton2" type="submit" class="art-button" id="UpdateButton2" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Purge"/>
        </form>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(56, 56, 57);"><br></span><span style="color: rgb(56, 56, 57);"><br>
        </span></p>
        <p></p><ul>
          <li><span style="font-size: 14px;">Receive Donation From</span>: <?php echo $row_User['ReceiveFrom2']; ?> : <?php echo $row_User['AcceptedFrom2']; ?></li>
        </ul>
        <form action="" method="post" name="Status1" id="Status2" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
          <input name="Confirm2" type="checkbox" id="Confirm2" value="Confirmed" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
          <label for="Confirm2"></label>
          <input name="UpdateButton3" type="submit" class="art-button" id="UpdateButton3" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Confirm"/>
          <input name="Purge2" type="checkbox" id="Purge2" value="You Will Be Rematched Soon!" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
          <label for="Purge2"></label>
          <input name="UpdateButton3" type="submit" class="art-button" id="UpdateButton4" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Purge"/>
        </form>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(56, 56, 57);"><br></span></p><p></p><p></p><p><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-6" style="width: 100%" >
        <p><br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 50%">
        <div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px"><p><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: rgb(23, 23, 23) 1px 0px 0px, rgb(23, 23, 23) -1px 0px 0px, rgb(23, 23, 23) 0px -1px 0px, rgb(23, 23, 23) 0px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.984375) 0px 0px 10px;">We Advice You Only Use Your Spare Cash!</span></p>

        <p><br>
        </p><br></div>
    </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 50%">
        <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">Contact Us: <span style="font-size: 15px;">turbofund2017@gmail.com</span></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%">
        <p>Copyright © 2011 TurboFund. All Rights Reserved.<br></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <p class="art-page-footer">
        <span id="art-footnote-links">Designed by <a href="www.turbofund.org" target="_blank">TurboFund</a>.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>
</body></html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($User);
?>
```

Comment: Since you store the time the account was created, you can compute and display the delta time. (time now minus time created). You don't really need a countdown for that, but you could, starting from the moment the delta is generated, count backwards.
You won't get by without at least basic programming skills, though

Comment: ok am assuming i can do this in phpmyadmin, is there no simple way i can use to do this. setting up a time stamp that will countdown from a specific time upon registration

Answer (score 0):

You can store **timestamp** in a field of user table when registering new user. also you can use mysql insert **trigger** to do that automatically for you.

when user logged in, you can subtract registered timestamp from current timestam and show in user dashboard.

also you can use JavaScript to continues showing counting down timer in in user dashboard with interval or setTimeout.

---

**Edited :**

to set timestamp in you table you can simply Default value to your field, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `schema`.`users` 
CHANGE COLUMN `created` `created` DATETIME NOT NULL 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON Insert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

> Note: getting timestamp is a bit different in mysql and php.

when your try to login or when your Job fired, you can check time and delete user if time is more than 3 hours an user don't finish registration steps. something like below **php** code:

```
if($row["approved"]!=true)//check if user didn't finish registration steps
{
$timest = $row["created"];//you must getting $row info from user table   

$registerTime = strtotime($timest);

$curentTime = time();

if(($curentTime-$registerTime) > 10800) {     //(60*60*3) seconds
  //Delelet your user
}
}
```

Comment: okay you mean timestamp from database, please can you explain to me how to properly set this trigger to delete a user after 3 hours so i can display that on a user php page..

Comment: delete user can be happened via jobs or when you retrieve user info from database by checking timestamp.

Comment: please i am new to phpmyadmin mysql setup, i only know how to set it to record time of registered user but i dont know how i can set it to countdown from a particular time.

Comment: Please could you tell me where i can place this code?